# Why do I get Liquibase Checksum verification error while starting a Corda Node

Tags: corda

I have run the Corda DB Migration tool and created a .jar containing .sql scripts of the tables that represent the States Objects of my CordApps as explained in https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html#database-management-tool
However after putting the .jar in the /cordapps folder of my node, I got an error indicating the Checksum Verification is failing: "**liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed: 2 change sets check sum...**"

Do you know how could I reset the checksum of my objects so that the verification does not fail and I could start the Corda Node successfully?

Thank you

Stan

Answer (score 0):

Truncate your migration related table i.e. `databasechangelog` & `databasechangeloglock`. I think truncating only `databasechangelog` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Hi Kid101, In my case I had to drop all the tables (including sequences) and run the "export-migration" again. Thank you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you change existing migration scripts which have been run previously. Corda will attempt to check the migration scripts against what has been run and find that the scripts no longer match.

For example: "MyApp" version 1.0 has a migration "init" script that creates table `FooBar`. On starting the node the table is created and the `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` tables insert a record the migration.

Then "MyApp" version 1.1 comes out which has a modified version of the "init" script. This new script matches the name of the script previously run on version 1.0 but no longer matches the checksum as the content has changed.

Kid101's solution does work but you would only need to delete the relevant entry for the changed script in `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock`. Also note that new Corda nodes will skip the original migration and start on version 1.1 which will bypass the issue.